# find camera/image obstructed by an object with opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

I have a FOV camera that has approximately **195*130** degree. So this 'lens' will put in a circle holder and the lens should **not** see the holder. Here's the image of **not** I want.

I draw 4 rectangle in Paint. There are 4 black spots which is the holder. The full red one is for censorship **not** there actually

[image]

If the camera image streams like that, that's a **no**. I need to detect that **black spots** and if it is like this it should gives me a **error message** or simply **'false'**. I searched google and couldn't found this. I'm a noob of this subject but if you explain me how to do this I can connect the dots.

Thank you for your helps.

*And I get the stream via USB-Capture Card. It acts like webcam.*

#UPDATE1: I cropped the four corners of image then get the threshold. Made a basic if else logic and get what I want. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I am not sure it is clear what you are really after. Perhaps some rewording / something to show what have you attempted could be useful.

Comment: try machine translation. language barrier definitely makes it hard to even understand what you want. please review [ask].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is it not clear? I need to find out is camera blocked by an object. I explained it literally. I show the picture. Look at the corners. It is black. Which means **camera is blocked by an object, the holder of the camera.** So I need to detect if it is blocked by the holder. I keep changing the position of the camera, i guess this was not that clear but arguably.

Answer (score 0):

Try detection by generating custom HAAR filters.

Or make it simply by applying a threshold (nearly black) and look if some tiny squares in the corneres are completely black.

Comment: Thank you i will check the second suggestion. I think i don't have time to learn and code the first one.